# Chrome crashes when re accessing the page that is using howler.js library

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, howler.js

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. enter http://www.javascriptoo.com/howler-js
2. go to examples on the top on the page
3. press "back" chrome button

the crash report is not generated for this bug.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

It's solved in latest Chrome beta. Not sure what you can do in the meantime - we just replaced the library instead.